# Learn Javascript : Higher Order Function

Tags: javascript

anyone can explain this code..? especially "**action(i)**" in *for* scope. i'm new in JS

```js
function repeat(n,action){
    for(let i= 1; i<=n; i++){
        action(i);
    }
}

repeat(10, console.log);
repeat(3, alert);
```

Comment: In the first call, value of `action` parameter is `console.log`, so `action(i)` is `console.log(i)`. In the second call, value of `action` parameter is `alert`, so `action(i)` is `alert(i)`

Comment: See [What is a callback function?](/q/824234/4642212), and [Higher-order functions in Javascript](/q/23535316/4642212).

Comment: @Yousaf  so 'action' in 'action(i)' act as second argument for first call and second call

Comment: @connexo 'action' is a function too.. that's what i got in your description

Comment: See [What is meant by 'first class object'?](/q/705173/4642212).

Comment: @Dedec action is only a function if repeat is called with an actual function as a second parameter. It is not a function by itself; when called with a function as a 2nd parameter, action is assigned that function.

Comment: I've added a more simplified example to my answer. Please let me know if anything remains unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Higher order function are functions that take other functions as parameter(s). It is based on functions being so-called *first-class-members* in Javascript, which says, among other things, this: functions can be passed to other functions, as parameters.

In your example the passed function *inside* the `repeat`function is called `action`, which is defined by your repeat function signature `(n,action)` (regardless of any name the actual function that is being passed in might already have), so whatever function gets passed into `repeat` is callable inside it using `action()`.

Please note that there is no way to guarantee that the actual call will have a `function` as a second parameter; noone can prevent somebody from making calls like `repeat('foo', 'bar')` or even `repeat()`. It is your job as a developer to make your function failsafe in this regard, or to take the *shit in, shit out*  standpoint.

A more simplified example would be this:

```js
function showMessage(message, showMethod) {
  showMethod(message);
}

showMessage('Hello world shown by console.log', console.log);

showMessage('Hello world shown by alert', alert);

showMessage('Hello world shown by console.error', console.error);
```

- `showMessage` is a function that shows a `message`, which it expects to be the first parameter when it is called.
- The actual function that should be used to display the passed `message` needs to be passed into `showMessage` as a second parameter.
- When called, `showMessage` runs the function that was passed as a second parameter (which is renamed to `showMethod` inside `showMessage`), passing `message` to it.

Another more practical use case could be this:

```js
function add(x, y) { return x + y; }
function subtract(x, y) { return x - y; }
function multiply(x, y) { return x * y; }
function divide(x, y) { return x / y; }

function calculate(x, y, calcFunction) { 
  const result = calcFunction(x, y);
  return result;  
}

console.log(calculate(2, 5, add));
console.log(calculate(2, 5, subtract));
console.log(calculate(2, 5, multiply));
console.log(calculate(2, 5, divide));
```

Comment: what confuse me about the code in my question is theres's no _'function'_ before _'action(i)'_ . so i didn't know what is _that_ anyway

Answer (score 2):

The code above simply repeats a given function (the action function) `n` amount of times, passing `i` (the current iteration) into the function

e.g.:

```js
repeat(10, console.log);
```

That repeats console.log 10 times. console.log is a function, which is passed in as the action function. Then it is run 10 times.